# How can we find element orders of a finite group?

Tags: finite-groups

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are two prime divisor of the order of a finite group $G$. I want to know if $G$ has an element of order $pq$ using the character table of $G$. Is this possible? If so,  please suggest a method.

Comment: Such an element always exists in abelian groups, but not necessarily in non-abelian groups (e.g. $S_3$).  I know of a proof, but unfortunately it doesn't use the character table of the group.

Comment: Not sure how much of this can be seen from the character table, but the existence of said element is equivalent to the existence of elements of orders $p$ and $q$ which commute (which is then to some extend related to how the conjugacy classes look, so being able to tell from the character table is not completely improbable).

Comment: So if there is a method to find out existence of said elements in any finite group even without usage of character table what will be that method?